# textarea removes whitelines?

Tags: asp.net, textarea

I have multiline textbox in ASP.NET which renders to a textarea element. I set the Text property to a string like

```
test\r\n\r\n\r\ntest2
```

but it only renders like

```
test
test2
```

in the textarea while I expected something like this to be rendered:

```
test


test2
```

It seems the textarea eats the whitelines. How to overcome this?

Comment: which encoding are you using?

Comment: This is not going to help, but just to let you know that I tested the code in ASP.NET 2.0 using IE 6.0 & Chrome and they both rendered correctly (i.e. with the line breaks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that somewhere in the pipeline was a whitespace remover installed which also ate the whitelines in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

That is a behaviour of html rendering - when you have consecutive white space then only the first instance gets rendered. In your case you could replace the CRLFs with a break tag instead (Thats a 'br' between angle brackets, i'm not quite sure how to get it to render correctly within the post).

Comment: Lets seee if it renders properly in the comment: you want this html tag <br/>